# awk to split field twice using two deliminator with condition

Tags: awk

In the `awk` I am splitting on the `space` or `:` after the `chrxx` (it is not consistent so I added both as `FS`, then splitting on the `-`. I can not seem to duplicate `$2` if there is no `-` after it. Lines 2,3 are examples. If there is a `-` after the number then the value to the right of it is `$3` in the ouput. The `awk` seems close but isn't duplicating the value. Thank you :).

**in**

```
chr17 7124137-7124146 ACADVL
chr1 229568460 ACTA1
chr10 90708637 ACTA2
```

**awk**

```
awk -F"[ :-]" '$3=$3?$3:$2' OFS='\t' in
```

**current**

```
chr17   7124137 7124146 ACADVL
chr1    229568460   ACTA1
chr10   90708637    ACTA2
```

**desired output**

```
chr17   7124137 7124146 ACADVL
chr1    229568460   229568460   ACTA1
chr10   90708637    90708637    ACTA2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If number of fields is three, copy 3rd field to 4th, and 2nd to 3rd. Force recomputing of whole record to make output tab separated regardless of what's done before.

```
awk -F'[ :-]' 'NF==3{$4=$3;$3=$2} {$1=$1} 1' OFS='\t' in
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -lane 'if($F[1]=~/\-/){$F[1]=~s/-/ /}else{splice @F, 1, 0, $F[1];}print "@F" ' temp
chr17 7124137 7124146 ACADVL
chr1 229568460 229568460 ACTA1
chr10 90708637 90708637 ACTA2
[netcrk@o2uk1061 infinys_root]$
```